# Should I add an optional class member using std::optional or inheritance?

Tags: c++, inheritance, architecture, option-type

I have `class Item`, one of no interest itself. However, I need some `Item`s to be gear like clothes or weapons which need to additionally store an `enum class Limb` object which represents the body part where they can be equipped. Moreover, ordinary `Item`s must be placed together with "gear" `Item`s in a single STL container and possibly be taken out later, maybe as a "gear" `Item`. I see two options here: inheritance

```
class Item { /* ... */ };
class Gear : public Item {
  Limb limb;
// ...
};
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Item>> items;
std::unique_ptr<Gear> gear = // dynamic cast items[...] and check for success
```

or `std::optional`

```
class Item {
  std::optional<Limb> limb; // if equippable, limb.has_value() == true
// ...
};
std::vector<Item> items;
Item gear = // get items[...] and check limb.has_value()
```

I like the first one for extensibility and compile-time type checking when a function expects `Gear` (not just an `Item`) instead of a runtime `assert(item.is_gear())` inside it.

The second one seems better in terms of speed (I like to care about it even when there are no performance issues expected) and design naturalness: I don't need to know about any other `class`es and special use cases when engineering `Item` (for example, making its destructor `virtual` like in the first variant would destroy this) which seems like clean and innocent design.

Which decision would be better and why? Or is there an even better solution?

Comment: Does it make sense for an Item (or Gear) to "have-a" limb?  Or should the Limb(s) be elsewhere (on the player, monster, creature, entity, ...) and the Items etc. have a pointer/reference/identifier as to which limb they are on?  Incidentally, `Item gear = ` will result in [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing).

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I understand `Item`s' `limb` as the information where they should be worn. After all, it's just an `enum` object, not the limb itself. Besides, there's only one `Limb` where an `Item` is supposed to be on (maybe none).

Comment: It is unclear from the question what, exactly, `Limb` is.  I assumed it was a class.  [Edit] the question to include that detail.  That then opens up the possibility of a `Limb` value for `NO_LIMB`, which you could use instead of `std::optional` to indicate something is not equippable/equipped.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm it is stated `Limb` is an `enum class` above the code. I don't like `Limb::none` as it's dependent design: it leads to shaping `Limb` like I need in one (!) of use cases, so `Limb`'s "logic" loses independency. Nevertheless, even if I make a "null" value, I would like to deeply compare it with the first approach in the question.

Comment: A minor point, but this discussion shows how naming variables well helps  Instead of "Limb limb", a name like "Limb placement" might have helped.

Comment: @lan4264 `placement` is still imperfect: for example, someone's inventory may be an `Item`'s placement :D I actually prefix enums in my usual code so it should be clear anyway; in examples here I'm sticking to a more widely-used convention.